# How to owner-draw on VCL-styled Page Control

Tags: delphi, canvas, delphi-10-seattle, ownerdrawn, tpagecontrol

When I have this:

```
if not _nightMode then
  TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Windows', False);
```

I can owner-draw on Page Control:

```
procedure TMyMainForm.pcDetailedDrawTab(Control: TCustomTabControl; TabIndex: Integer;
    const Rect: TRect; Active: Boolean);
var
  can: TCanvas;
  cx, by: Integer;
  aclr: TColor;
begin
  if pcDetailed.Pages[TabIndex] = tsActualData then begin
    can := pcDetailed.Canvas;
    cx := Rect.Left + Rect.Width div 2;
    by := Rect.Bottom - 2;
    if _nightMode then aclr := clWhite else aclr := clBlack;
    can.Pen.Color := aclr;
    can.Brush.Color := aclr;
    can.Polygon([Point(cx - 10, by - 10), Point(cx + 10, by - 10), Point(cx, by)]);
  end;
end;
```

When I have this:

```
if _nightMode then
  TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Cobalt XEMedia', False);
```

my drawn triangle goes lost.

How to draw a triangle with any VCL style?

Delphi 10 Seattle.

Comment: It's VCL styles rather than themed. And the version of Delphi often matters for such questions.

Answer (score 3):

When [`Styles`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/VCL_Styles_Overview) other than the native 'Windows'-style are chosen a `StyleHook`-class will begin to hook paint relevant windows messages to controls. There are different `StyleHook` classes for different control classes.

In case of the `TPageControl` it is the `TTabControlStyleHook`. The hook-class-combination is registered with `TCustomStyleEngine.RegisterStyleHook(TCustomTabControl, TTabControlStyleHook);` in the class constructor of `TCustomTabControl`. This hook class is overriding the controls paint, because it will paint the `TCustomTabControl` itself when a Style is enabled.

What can be done is unregister the default `TStyleHookClass` and register one that will let the developer paint:

```
  TCustomStyleEngine.UnRegisterStyleHook(TCustomTabControl, TTabControlStyleHook);
  TCustomStyleEngine.RegisterStyleHook(TCustomTabControl, TMyTabControlStyleHook);
```

Where `TMyTabControlStyleHook` is following:

```
type
  TMyTabControlStyleHook = class(TTabControlStyleHook)
  public
    constructor Create(AControl: TWinControl); override;
  end;

constructor TMyTabControlStyleHook.Create(AControl: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited Create(AControl);
  OverridePaint := False;
end;
```

This is however not the exact equivalent to only painting the tabs in the `TPageControl`, as the `TTabControlStyleHook` is responsible for painting the complete `TPageControl` control.

But `TTabControlStyleHook` has the `procedure DrawTab(Canvas: TCanvas; Index: Integer); virtual;` which can be overridden for that.

```
type
  TMyTabControlStyleHook = class(TTabControlStyleHook)
  strict protected
    procedure DrawTab(Canvas: TCanvas; Index: Integer); override;
  end;

procedure TMyTabControlStyleHook.DrawTab(Canvas: TCanvas; Index: Integer);
begin
  DrawTabOverride(Canvas, Index, TabRect[Index], TCustomTabControl(Control).MouseInClient);
end;
```

Where `DrawTabOverride` is something like this

```
procedure DrawTabOverride(Canvas: TCanvas;
  TabIndex: Integer; const Rect: TRect; Active: Boolean);
```

so it can be called in the `OnDrawTab` event when drawing native and in the StyleHook class `DrawTab` when styled.